# Change DNS for particular browser only?

Tags: dns

I'd like to change DNS for particular browser only (Chrome or Firefox). I don't want to edit hosts file because I don't want complete system to override the IP for the domain. I just need THE ONE BROWSER to do this. Is there a way except advanced fiddling with proxy ?

Comment: Very good question. I'm interested in a solution myself. If you clarified what website (Netflix, Hulu etc.)you wanted to access with the different DNS then there might be other solutions available.

Comment: It is my website. My domain - I am changing frameworks AND hosting companies and adding stuff manually from one to another. That's why I need to access old LIVE version and at the same time to alter the new version.

Comment: @Greenleader if that's the reason, how about using the IP addresses instead? Until the switch is complete...

Comment: Oh man. Just realized that this question is nearly 3 years old...

Comment: Heck, I want to set DNS settings for a specific tab... and leave the rest of the browser-verse alone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no other way but to use the hosts file.
Check this addon can help you somehow [`SwitchHosts`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchhosts/) for Firefox.

Comment: SwitchHosts appears to be long gone, as of 2023...

Answer (score 5):

There are several plugins for popular browsers that will allow you to make this change without editing system files. This is one of the fastest and easiest ways to check your server before pointing your domain.

All plugins require your desired host and your server IP to load it from. Each plugin will have different instructions to use. Instructions for proper use may differ based on version.

Here below are the plugins/addons I found (before installing, heck if they're still maintained and compatible with your browser's version).

#### Chrome

Virtual Hosts

[Install Virtual Hosts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-hosts/aiehidpclglccialeifedhajckcpedom?hl=en)

[image: Virtual Hosts]

- Enter the fully qualified domain name in the **VHost Domain** field
- Enter the destination IP address in the **VHost IP** field
- Tick the **enable** check box

HostSwitch Plus

[Install HostSwitch Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/host-switch-plus/bopepoejgapmihklfepohbilpkcdoaeo)

[image: HostSwitch Plus]
* Enter the destination IP address in the **IP** field
* Specify the fully qualified domain name in the **Domain** field

#### Firefox

Switch Hosts

[Install Switch Hosts](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/switchhosts/)

HostAdmin

[Install HostAdmin](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/hostadmin/)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a DNS server, but Host Switch Plus[1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/host-switch-plus/bopepoejgapmihklfepohbilpkcdoaeo) on Chrome worked for me. It also allows multiple entries with tagging for dev, prod and test. I primarily use it when I am testing a site allowing the other browsers to access the production site as well.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.